# Convert each matrix column to a sub-matrix and loop through each sub-matrix for plotting

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I have a data frame with factors like this:

```
rss<-c("rs","total","rs","total","total","total","rs","rs")
css<-c("G","S","S","Q","Q","Q","G","G")
batch<-c("5","6","6","7","7","8","7","5")
dat<-data.frame(rss,css,batch)
```

I want to plot the numeric matrix of the above data frame for each column, i.e. convert the 8*3 matrix to 3,4*2 sub-matrices by column. That way I can loop through and plot the sub-matrix data.

```
newdat<-data.matrix(dat)
split.dat<-split(newdat,col(newdat))
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
for(i in split.dat){image(array(i,c(4,2)))}
```

Are there any better ways to doing the same? Would also appreciate any suggestions for plotting such data other than `image`

Answer (score 2):

Here are some other options, though the way you're doing it is fine.

```
apply(newdat, 2, function(i) image(matrix(i, 4, 2)))
```

Or, using `raster` instead

```
library(raster)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
apply(newdat, 2, function(i) plot(raster(matrix(i, 4, 2))) # plot as raster
# or
apply(newdat, 2, function(i) plot(raster(matrix(i, 4, 2)), useRaster=FALSE))
# pictured below, uses image()
```

[image]

Or using `persp`

```
nr <- 4
nc <- 2
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
apply(newdat, 2, function(i)
   persp(0:nc, 0:nr, matrix(1, (nc+1), (nr+1)), zlim=c(0,2), phi=270,
       box=FALSE, col = t(matrix(i, 4, 2))))
# the color matrix here is using the integers to define colors, but you may want to adjust that.
```

[image]

Or `levelplot` from `lattice`:

```
library(lattice)
library(gridExtra) # for grid.arrange()
p1 <- levelplot(t(apply(matrix(newdat[,1], 2, 4, byrow=TRUE), 1, rev)))
p2 <- levelplot(t(apply(matrix(newdat[,2], 2, 4, byrow=TRUE), 1, rev)))
p3 <- levelplot(t(apply(matrix(newdat[,3], 2, 4, byrow=TRUE), 1, rev)))

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol=3)

# Or in a loop:
p <- apply(newdat, 2, function(i) levelplot(t(apply(matrix(i, 2, 4, byrow=TRUE), 1, rev))))

grid.arrange(p[[1]], p[[2]], p[[3]], ncol=length(p))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks very much for all your answers, they are helpful. I have used levelplot() before but not raster or persp

Answer (score 2):

I think this solves your problem with ggplot2. However, your data are in a strange format, and it's unclear why they should be plotted in the way you describe. It seems to me that there are some variables that are missing, specifically the ones corresponding to `row` and `col` in the `newdat` data frame I'm creating. I recommend you read the [tidy data paper](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) by Hadley Wickham.

```
require(tidyr)
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)

rss<-c("rs","total","rs","total","total","total","rs","rs")
css<-c("G","S","S","Q","Q","Q","G","G")
batch<-c("5","6","6","7","7","8","7","5")
dat<-data.frame(rss,css,batch)

# convert into tidy data frame
dat %>% mutate(col=c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4)), row=c(1:4, 1:4)) %>%
  gather(key, value, rss:batch) -> newdat

# plot
ggplot(newdat, aes(x=col, y=row, fill=value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  facet_wrap(~key) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=c(1,2), limits=c(1,2)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer and for the tidy data paper. The actual data has a column with sample # and the data frame I have used here is just a test. I'm trying to visualize a randomized layout ordered on the most important condition and ultimately choose an optimal layout based on all the three conditions